# How to copy a table in R

Tags: r

The problem I have is the following. I load my table from file

```
Table <- read.table(opt$input, header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
```

then I remove things I do not need

```
TT<-Table[(Table[,2] != "XZ" & Table[,1] != "N" & Table[,1] != ""),]
```

then I compute frequencies

```
Freq<-table(TT[,1], TT[,2])
```

but I get

```
        A XZ B
      0  0   0       0
  s   0  1   0       3
  c   0 28   0      83
  N   0  0   0       0
```

So the values have been removed but placeholders : XZ(col), ""(col), N(row) have stayed. How to eliminate those. Is there a way to copy a table but not by reference but by value so the placeholders are skipped

Comment: you could specify which columns(/rows) you want to stay: `newt <- oldt[, 1]` or which you don't want to stay: `newt <- oldt[, -1]`. I think it works with names too (not sure).

Comment: Try `table(droplevels(TT))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this (remove factor levels that are dropped):

```
TT<-Table[(Table[,2] != "XZ" & Table[,1] != "N" & Table[,1] != ""),]

TT[,1] <- factor(TT[,1])
TT[,2] <- factor(TT[,2])
```

and then

```
Freq<-table(TT[,1], TT[,2])
```

Comment: @JohnDoe You should "accept the answer" if it did. (The tick on the left side under votes - it should turn green.)